# Remove Active Class on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now I have a menu/sub menus that I am adding active classes to on click. I would like to remove the active class if I click the same menu Item twice. My initial thought was to just toggle the active class in jQuery but that does not seem to work. Any thoughts?? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menusomething li a").on("click", function() {
        $("#menusomething li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
#menusomething li a{color :green}
#menusomething li a.active{color :red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menusomething" style="padding-left:30px">
                          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                          <li><a class="target" href="#">CHAPTERS</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
                             <li><a href="#">Dallas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Northern California</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Orange County</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Phoenix</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">San Diego</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Washington DC</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                          <li><a href="#">MEMBER SERVICES</a>
                           <ul class="submenu">
                             <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Service2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Service3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Service4</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                          <li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">MENU ITEM 2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
        $("#menusomething li a").removeClass("active");
```

as together with the toggle it will make the class to be added again, and so you can never actually remove it.

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menusomething li a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menusomething li a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
#menusomething li a{color :green}
#menusomething li a.active{color :red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menusomething" style="padding-left:30px">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a class="target" href="#">CHAPTERS</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
     <li><a href="#">Dallas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Northern California</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Orange County</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Phoenix</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">San Diego</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Washington DC</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEMBER SERVICES</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
     <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service4</a></li>
    </ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">MENU ITEM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MENU ITEM 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: YOU are awesome! Thank you